# How to parse url in <a alt="url attribute"">

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have html code on a site:

```
<a alt="Кроссовки adidas. Цвет черный. Категории: Женская обувь, Лучшие отзывы, Кеды, кроссовки, ботинки. Вид 3." 
class="enabledZoom MagicThumb-swap" href="http://img2.site.ru/big/120000/129102-3.jpg" rel="zoom-id:Azoom;zoom-width:450;zoom-height:598;zoom-distance:10;zoom-position:right;opacity:50;" 
rev="http://img2.site.ru/large/120000/129102-3.jpg" style="outline: 0px; " id="mt-1334303054133">
<img src="http://img2.site.ru/tm/120000/129102-3.jpg" class=""></a>
```

How to extract "http://img2.site.ru/**large**/120000/129102-3.jpg" with nokogiri gem?

P.S. Nokogiri is parsing element :

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x42c1ad8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c1a7e name="alt" value="Кроссовки adidas. Цвет черный. Категории: Женская обувь, Лучшие отзывы, Кеды, кроссовки, ботинки. Вид 1.">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c1a74 name="class" value="enabledZoom">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c1a6a name="href" value="http://img2.site.ru/big/120000/129102-1.jpg">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c1a60 name="rel" value="zoom-id:Azoom;zoom-width:450;zoom-height:598;zoom-distance:10;zoom-position:right;opacity:50;">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c1a4c name="rev" value="http://img2.site.ru/large/120000/129102-1.jpg">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x42c0ee4 name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c0e94 name="src" value="http://img2.site.ru/tm/120000/129102-1.jpg">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x42c0e8a name="class" value="current">]>]>]
```

Comment: found_elements.first['rev'] ??

Comment: @Dmitry is correct given your nokogiri response. However, your parse will be more robust and you won't need the `first` if you identify the element more precisely, as @theTinMan is showing you. If you provide the Nokogiri search code and a larger HTML sample, we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `at` method if you know the `<img>` tag you want is in the first `<a>` tag:

```
doc.at('a img')['src'] => "http://img2.site.ru/tm/120000/129102-3.jpg"
```

If it's not, then you'll need to isolate the `<a>` or the `<img>`. I'd probably go after the `<a id="...">` using something like:

```
doc.at('a#mt-1334303054133 img')['src'] => "http://img2.site.ru/tm/120000/129102-3.jpg"
```

If there are multiple `<a>` or `<img>` tags then your sample isn't good enough and we'd need more information about the HTML you're receiving.